# ¿Mandar el archivo a otra página?

Tags: php, html, archivo

Recojo los datos de un formulario que está en index.html, cuando lo envían se genera un PDF que está en envio.php y los datos se guardan en un archivo de texto.
¿Cómo puedo mandar ese archivo a otra página? Por ejemplo, a registros.php para que puedan descargar ese archivo. ¿Podrían darme alguna idea? Anexo parte de los códigos:

index.html

```
<form class = "formulario" id = "formulario" role="form" action="enviodemail.php" method="POST" >

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="titulo">Título de la obra *</label>
              <input id="titulo" type="text" required pattern="[A-Za-z0-9áéíóú ]+" name="titulo" class="form-control" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fecha">Fecha de creación *</label>
              <input id="fecha" type="date" name="fecha" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
```

envio.php

```
<?php

                  require("fpdf/fpdf.php");   

                  if(isset($_POST["titulo"]) && !empty($_POST["titulo"]) &&
                  isset($_POST["fecha"]) && !empty($_POST["fecha"]) &&
){

                    $aleatorio = rand(1, 30000);
                    $titulo = $_POST["titulo"];
                    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
                   $datos = fopen("datos_ilustradores.txt", "a");
                  fwrite($datos, "Folio: " . $aleatorio . " |");
                  fwrite($datos, " Titulo: " . $titulo . " |");
                  fwrite($datos, " Fecha: " . $fecha . " |");
 fclose($datos);
```

Comment: En el código que adjuntas no se ve que utilices fpdf para generar un PDF. Mira los ejemplos que te da la biblioteca (Supongo que es http://www.fpdf.org/)

Comment: Sí la uso pero no anexe el código, lo que importa es obtener el archivo. Por ejemplo, al ingresar ha
http://pagina.com/formatos/descargar.php en el archivo "descargar.php" tengo que poner un código para que me descargue el archivo "datos_ilustradores.txt".
Eso es lo que no puedo hacer.

Comment: podrías probar enviar el txt directamente a la salida con [readfile](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.readfile.php) luego de generar el archivo. Algo como :


``` 
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.txt"');
    readfile(path);
```


De otro modo sería que guardes los txt en una carpeta pública con nombre únicos, luego debería generar el link correspondiente.

Comment: Ya lo logré, pero el problema es que lo probé de manera local y cuando lo subí al servidor, no crea el archivo para guardar los dato. ¿Sabes qué puede ser?